# Is there a way to simultaneously display 3 different computers desktops on one projector or television?

Tags: multiple-monitors, projector

I know that some projectors/TVs have a PIP (Picture in Picture) function but I have only seen it with at most two different input sources being simultaneously displayed on the same monitor.  I think EPSON has a multiview technology in some of their projectors but I was wondering if there is an adapter similar to a KVM Switch that could perform this function but just do it simultaneously? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Have you just searched for a device that allows this? I mean, it should be on their features.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can.

You can hook up 1 pc to a beamer/tv and use Remote Desktop or teaviewer or vnc viewer etc to take over the other 2 pc's.

If you have windows 8.1 you can use smart sizing inside Microsoft Remote Desktop to scale the image down. Programs such as teamviewer and vnc also offer sizing.

Comment: That is a good idea LPChip but I would probably go with VNC as one of my environments is going to be a UNIX like environment.  Thanks for the good answer.

Comment: I once wrote a VNC "tiling concentrator" that would accept incoming connections from one or more VNC viewers, and make outgoing connections to multiple VNC servers.  It then did math on the incoming data streams to shift the pixel positions sent by each server around so that each server's screen data showed up in an adjusted relative position on the viewer.  The VNC wire protocol was well-designed in only one aspect -- it's lightweight -- but it's otherwise somewhat delicate.  This was so long ago that I'd be embarrassed to share the code (if I could find it) but it can be done that way, too.

Answer (score 5):

I like LPChip's answer better as it's much cheaper (much much cheaper).

If you wanted a hardware solution [this](http://www.networktechinc.com/quad-splitter.html) looks to do what you want, but it's going to set you back a few grand.

Comment: When you said "it's going to set you back a few grand.", I though you were 'joking'. What a time to be wrong...

Comment: Sadly not.  I don't know if there are cheaper options out there, that one was the first one I found.

Comment: I've found, a few years ago, a splitter for 3 screens. But it was only VGA and required an abnormally huge resolution to work.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for but as you have already stated it is way out of my price range. This is a good answer just not the one I was looking for but hopefully in the next few years someone will come out with a cheaper version of this hardware for home use.

Answer (score 0):

I've found Microsoft's [Remote Desktop Connection Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989) to be remarkably useful when managing multiple RDP sessions.

It's free, and you can organise your servers into a tree of sub-groupings, remember logon credentials for each server or group, or inherit from the parent group (or just prompt you for them), and the thumbnail images of each server are resizable and live, meaning you can actually click into them without having to expand each one. This makes doing batch installs of software really easy, and if you make them big enough you can use it for what you need (I run with the thumbnails scaled so big that only two fit in the width of my monitor, it works well for actually using the machines at that scale).

I see you said that at least one of the machines is running Linux, but that shouldn't be a problem thanks to [XRDP](http://www.xrdp.org/).